# Why is my rubber tree's leave just falling?

Tags: houseplants

Not sure when the last time the plant was watered. I had just purchased this from homedepot and brought it home. I went to water it today and noticed one leave had just fallen "cleanly" off. And then another fell with a *slight* touch. After that I was too nervous to touch the plant again in case other leaves "just falls off". Any idea what might cause this?
[image]

[image]